# Trigger.IO - Cancelling Facebook UI dialogue fires success callback

Tags: facebook, trigger.io

I am using the forge facebook api to open a feed dialogue to post images to a users wall. If the user clicks 'Cancel' instead of 'Share', the success callback is still fired. If the user clicks the close ( x ) button the error callback is fired correctly.

```
    forge.facebook.ui(
          {
            method: 'feed',
            link: link,
            picture: model.get('file').url,
            name: name,
            caption: caption,
            description: 'Lorem Ipsum'
          },
          function(response) {

            // Called when user clicks cancel.

            forge.notification.create(
              'Great!',
              'Item has been posted to your wall',
              function() {

              },
              function(error) {
                forge.logging.error(JSON.stringify(error));
              }
            );

          },
          function (e) {
            // Called when user closes dialogue but not on cancel.
            forge.logging.info('facebook failed: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
          }
        );
```

Comment: Have you checked the response to see if it's passing any data you can go off of?

Comment: Yes, I've checked the response and it's undefined in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'd tend to agree this is unexpected behaviour - however it's consistent across several Facebook-supplied SDKs and has been for some time so we've passed it through as-is.

If the user hits the `x` at the top left of the dialog, your error callback will be invoked. If the user cancels the dialog, your success callback will be invoked with `{}` as the callback parameter.

I'd recommend checking for that case with something like:

```
forge.facebook.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        link: link,
    },
    function (response) {
        if (JSON.stringify(response) === "{}") {
            handleCancel();
        } else {
            handleSuccess(response);
        }
    }
    function (error) {
        handleError(error);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks James. The problem is the response callback parameter is exactly the same for both cancel and save. i.e. JSON.stringify(response) returns **null**. So checking for JSON.stringify(response) === "{}" will not return true in either case. Is it expected that the SDK returns an empty response on 'Save'?

Comment: I see this was fixed in v1.4.23. http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-23